# Can't get input stream from URL

Tags: java, url, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, discord-jda

I'm trying to get a BufferedImage from an URL, but it throws me an IIOException. I already checked the URL and It works fine.

Exception:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1395)
de.visionvenue.statify.objects.Statistics.<init>(Statistics.java:60)
de.visionvenue.statify.commands.SetupCommand.onCommand(SetupCommand.java:67)
de.visionvenue.statify.manager.CommandManager.lambda$0(CommandManager.java:26)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is the code that where I try to get the BufferedImage

```
URL img = new URL(settings.getGuild().getIconUrl());
            
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(img);
```

The URL is

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/712313516542918717/8b1e61da607cdd67546ffba653a12604.png
```

Comment: Works fine here. ```URL img = new URL("https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/712313516542918717/8b1e61da607cdd67546ffba653a12604.png"); BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(img);```.

Could you try to run the code above in a unittest and see if it runs ok?

Comment: I also tried it in a blank project. It worked. For more Information see the comments in the first answer.

Comment: When it worked, then your problem is somewhere in `settings.getGuild().getIconUrl()`.

Comment: Its a Problem with the request of the URL. I use the JDA and I think Discord Bots can only get the raw URL but not the file/image out of it. How could I "emulate" that the application is not a Discord Bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the few code fragments, it is hard to see the cause as it works for other users as seen in the comments.

---

Original answer:

You want to use the [URLConnection class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) instead.

You can then call `.connect()` and [`.getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()).

---

If you need more sophisticated logic and better APIs, I would recommend to use either [Apache HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (for any HTTP calls) or the [JAX-RS client](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxrs-client002.html) which is best suited for REST-based connections, but can also be used for any other url connection. The advantage of the latter is that multiple implementations exist (resteasy, jersey, CXF, just to name a few).

Comment: I get an Error 403 if I try to use the URLConnection.

Comment: I tried using the Apache HTTPClient and it worked. Thank you for the recomendation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openStream()` method in `URL`, as follow:

```
String url = settings.getGuild().getIconUrl();
URL img = new URL(url);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(img.openStream());
```

Comment: Don't works. I get an Error 403